# What are cuboids and how do they work

Tags: olap-cube

I new to multidimensional modelling. I was reading into OLAP cubes and come across cuboids I am very confused about what they are and how they work. For example if we 3D olap cube which has Product, Time, Location as it axises how many cuboids are there. What is the difference between a cuboid and base cuboid.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to forget about the number of dimensions. In non-OLAP terminology a cube refers to a three dimensional shape of equal size on each dimension. In OLAP terminology a cube can have as many dimensions as there is data, and the number of elements in each dimension can differ. E.g. a 'sales' cube can be associated with dimensions such as Product, Time, City, Basket Size, Sales Channel, Price Band, etc. It's still called a cube.

The term cuboid is just referring to taking a slice of a cube and either ignoring or else fixing the value in one or more of the dimensions. Given your example, if you were to ignore the Location dimension then the resulting dataset would be a cuboid where your data varied by Time and Product only (and was thus implicitly covering all Locations). And even though this only leaves two dimensions, we still call it a cube.

As described [on this blog](http://bukhantsov.org/2012/05/olap-cube/) OLAP systems will often store pre-calculated aggregated figures for different cuboids to allow for more efficient processing of aggregate queries.